# Verilog Making a divide by two counter out of D Flip Flops not working

Tags: verilog, fpga, test-bench

I have a working DFF under the module below.

```
d_flip_flop_edge_triggered DFFT(Q, Qn, C, D);
```

However when I switch the "D" input to "Qn" - to make a devide-by-2 counter - the test bench output does not show either Q or Qn. Its red as if there was an error.

Here's the full code:

```
module divBy2UsingDFF(Q, Qn, C, D
    );
   output Q;
   output Qn;
   input  C;
   input  D;
    wire Qn;
    d_flip_flop_edge_triggered DFFT(Q, Qn, C, Qn);

endmodule
```

I'm new to verilog and I am guessing its a syntax problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Q value in the simulator, since the red probably means `X`, which indicates that the data value of the flip-flop is undefined, which is usually the case after reset.

There are several ways to address this:

- Use a flip-flop with an asynchronous reset
- Add a synchronous load for the data flip-flop

Btw. instead of instantiating a DFFT you could write the flip-flop divider with an `always`.  Also the `wire Qn;` is not required.

Comment: Yes the Q value is X. I defined the input C in the simulator so I don't know why its showing that. It also has no reset.  I think the problem may be that I'm using Qn as both and output and an input?                                                      I'm not sure what you mean by writing it with     always?

Comment: No, use of Qn output to feed the input is fine, but the problem is that the internal flip-flop storage is initially undefined, thus has to be defined as either 0 or one after start.  Consider yourself; what is the initial value of a flip-flop after power on ?

Comment: The initial value is undefined! Ah I see what you are saying. Is there a way I could initiate the variable from within the code?

Comment: Suggestions for initialization are use FF with async reset, or load a value initially, as said in the bullets for "There are several ways to address this:".

Comment: Finally got it to work thanks to your suggestions. Thanks